# OpenVirtualDisk Function return ERROR_FILE_CORRUPT (1392) with ISO file

Tags: c++, mount, iso, vhd

I ran the openvirtualdisk function according to the attached code. However, it fails with a 1392 error(ERROR_FILE_CORRUPT).
According to msdn, the error is returned in the following cases.

This function will fail with error ERROR_FILE_CORRUPT (1392) if an ISO virtual disk is being opened and the file size is not an even multiple of 2 KB (2,048 bytes), is at least 34 KB (34,816 bytes), or the volume structure descriptor does not contain a known CDFS or UDFS volume identifier.

I am trying to mount an iso file from windows 10 1803 to 1809.
The size of the currently used iso file is 3.19GB, and the volume structure descriptor does not seem to be a problem.

What else do I need to check? Is there a problem with the code?

```
OPEN_VIRTUAL_DISK_PARAMETERS openParameters;
openParameters.Version = OPEN_VIRTUAL_DISK_VERSION_1;
openParameters.Version1.RWDepth = OPEN_VIRTUAL_DISK_RW_DEPTH_DEFAULT;

VIRTUAL_STORAGE_TYPE storageType;
storageType.DeviceID = VIRTUAL_STORAGE_TYPE_DEVICE_VHD;
storageType.VendorId = VIRTUAL_STORAGE_TYPE_VENDOR_MICROSOFT;

ATTACH_VIRTUAL_DISK_PARAMETERS attachParameters;
attachParameters.Version = ATTACH_VIRTUAL_DISK_VERSION_1;

HANDLE vhdHandle;

if (OpenVirtualDisk(&openStorageType, "{VHD PATH GOES HERE}", 
        VIRTUAL_DISK_ACCESS_ALL, OPEN_VIRTUAL_DISK_FLAG_NONE, 
        &openParameters, &vhdHandle) != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    // If return value of OpenVirtualDisk isn't ERROR_SUCCESS, there was a problem opening the VHD
}

// Warning: AttachVirtualDisk requires elevation
if (AttachVirtualDisk(vhdHandle, 0, ATTACH_VIRTUAL_DISK_FLAG_PERMANENT_LIFETIME,
        0, &attachParameters, 0) != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    // If return value of AttachVirtualDisk isn't ERROR_SUCCESS, there was a problem attach the disk
}
```